# What is $$ in bison?

Tags: c++, parsing, bison

In the bison manual in section [2.1.2 Grammar Rules for rpcalc](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_mono/bison.html#Rpcalc-Rules), it is written that:

> In each action, the pseudo-variable $$ stands for the semantic value
>   for the grouping that the rule is going to construct. Assigning a
>   value to $$ is the main job of most actions

Does that mean `$$` is used for holding the result from a rule? like:

```
exp exp '+'   { $$ = $1 + $2;      }
```

And what's the typical usage of `$$` after begin assigned to?

Comment: +1 for me coming this page from the exact google search.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, `$$` is used to hold the result of the rule. After being assigned to, it typically becomes a `$x` in some higher-level (or lower precedence) rule.

Consider (for example) input like `2 * 3 + 4`. Assuming you follow the normal precedence rules, you'd have an action something like: `{ $$ = $1 * $3; }`. In this case, that would be used for the `2 * 3` part and, obviously enough, assign `6` to `$$`. Then you'd have your `{ $$ = $1 + $3; }` to handle the addition. For this action, `$1` would be given the value `6` that you assigned to `$$` in the multiplication rule.

Answer (score 6):

> Does that mean `$$` is used for holding the result from a rule? like:

Yes.

> And what's the typical usage of `$$` after begin assigned to?

Typically you won’t need that value again. Bison uses it internally to propagate the value. In your example, `$1` and `$2` are the respective semantic values of the two `exp` productions, that is, their values were set somewhere in the semantic rule for `exp` by setting *its* `$$` variable.

Answer (score 4):

Try this. Create a YACC file with:

```
%token NUMBER
%%
exp:    exp '+' NUMBER  { $$ = $1 + $3; }
    |   exp '-' NUMBER  { $$ = $1 - $3; }
    |   NUMBER          { $$ = $1; }
    ;
```

Then process it using Bison or YACC. I am using Bison but I assume YACC is the same. Then just find the "#line" directives. Let us find the "#line 3" directive; it and the relevant code will look like:

```
#line 3 "DollarDollar.y"
    { (yyval) = (yyvsp[(1) - (3)]) + (yyvsp[(3) - (3)]); }
    break;
```

And then we can quickly see that "$$" expands to "yyval". That other stuff, such as "yyvsp", is not so obvious but at least "yyval" is.

Answer (score 1):

$$ represents the result reference of the current expression's evaluation. In other word, its result.Therefore, there's no particular usage after its assignation.

Bye !